# Nuxt video not loading on mount from URL

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

My video isn't loading when the component mounts

I've narrowed down the problem to having something to do with ":src" in my code. The video loads fine if i hard code the URL in however this is supposed to be a unique property for each user. a video avatar named "avatar" which contains the URL to the video.

The ":src" property works fine whenever i have the user load the video from their own files. However after the file is saved and converted to a URL it will no longer load on mount.

```html
<template v-if="this.type == 'image'">
    <b-img key="image" id="avatarPhoto" v-bind="profile" :src="avatar" class="avatarPhoto"></b-img>
</template>
<template v-else>
    <video playsinline autoplay loop muted key="video" id="avatarVideo" v-bind="profile" class="avatarVideo">
        <!-- the line causing the error is below -->
        <source id="videoSrc" :src="avatar">
    </video>
</template>
```

```html
<!-- this is how it renders on load with a URL for the prop -->

<video playsinline="" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" id="avatarVideo" class="avatarVideo">
     <source id="videoSrc" src="http://remoteserver.com/storage/avatar/profile/1558476637.mp4">
</video>
```

```html
<!-- this is how it looks when rendered from a file load which works fine but this does not happen on load -->

<video playsinline="" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" type="video" id="avatarVideo" width="281.25" height="auto" class="avatarVideo">
     <source id="videoSrc" src="data:video/quicktime;base64,blahblahblah">
</video>
```

```js
async created() {
    await this.$axios.get("profile")
        .then((response) => {
            this.form.fill(response.data.data)
            this.type = this.form.a_type.split('/').shift()
            this.avatar = response.data.data.avatar

            if (this.type === 'video'){
                this.getVideoDimensions()
                .then((dimensions) => {
                    this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
                    this.handleResize(dimensions)
                })
                .catch((e) =>{
                    this.toast('error',e.message)
                })
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response){
                console.log(error.response.data)
                this.toast('error', error.response.data.data[0])
            }
        })
    if (process.client){
        window.addEventListener('resize',this.handleResize)
    }
}
```

This is the example axios reponse requested by @Taro

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"xxx",
      "email":"xxx@xxx.com",
      "email_verified_at":null,
      "phone":null,
      "bio":null,
      "avatar":"http:\/\/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\/storage\/avatar\/profile\/1558476637.mp4",
      "a_ext":"mp4",
      "a_type":"video\/mp4",
      "a_dimensions":"height: 360 , width: 480",
      "background":"http:\/\/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\/img\/background.jpg",
      "b_ext":"jpg",
      "b_type":"image",
      "b_dimensions":null,
      "parent_id":null,
      "stripe_id":null,
      "card_brand":null,
      "card_last_four":null,
      "trial_ends_at":null,
      "created_at":"2019-05-21 20:52:31",
      "updated_at":"2019-05-21 22:10:37",
      "roles":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "created_at":"2019-05-21 20:52:31",
            "updated_at":"2019-05-21 20:52:31",
            "name":"Admin",
            "pivot":{
               "user_id":1,
               "role_id":1,
               "id":1
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "message":"Authenticated"
}
```

It doesn't cause an actual error but when i check the videos readyState it is a value of 0. No information is available about the media resource.

I expect the video to load with the returned URL but it does not. How can i resolve this issue?

*** Update

```js
data() {
    return {
        errors:{},
        profile: {},
        avatar: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/storage/avatar/profile/1558476637.mp4',
        type:'',
        form: this.$vform({
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            role: '',
            bio: '',
            avatar: '',
            a_ext: '',
            a_type:'',
            a_dimensions: {},
            background: '',
            b_ext: '',
            b_type:'',
            b_dimensions: {},
        })
    }
}
```

Upon further testing I suspect my avatar property is not being set fast enough for the video element to load. if i hard code a URL into the avatar property the video loads up fine so i think this code is mostly fine.

I have tried to execute the axios request during beforeCreate() as apposed to created(). However this does not work. I will continue testing.

This is actually kind of representing another issue i'm having with video elements in Nuxt as well. In Nuxt i am not able to dynamically change a video elements source and reload the video element. For example, When i have a user choose a video to upload initially it loads the video file fine. However, if the user decides that's not the video they want and tries to choose another. I can not figure a way to reload the video element with the new video file.

if the user chooses a image however my template code removes the video element from the DOM and inserts the image element. This resets the video element allowing the user to load up a new video if they want a different one. But a user can not choose two different videos in a row and have it load properly.

I'm not sure if there is something i am missing with working with video elements in general or with Nuxt or JS.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your axios response?

Comment: I added the axios response to the original post

Comment: you don't use 'this' in your template. `:src="avatar"`. also `v-if="type === 'image'"`

Comment: That's right as @Andrew1325 said, you've added the keyword this inside your template which is not needed.

Comment: I've made those corrections, however, it does not resolve my issue as i didn't think it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by excluding the initial video source element in the template code and edited the following code in my created() method to insert a dynamically created source element.

```js
if (this.type === 'video'){
    // new code that fixing video initial loading
    var video = document.getElementById('avatarVideo')
    var src = document.createElement('source')
    src.setAttribute('src',this.avatar)
    video.appendChild(src)

    this.getVideoDimensions()
    .then((dimensions) => {
        this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
        this.handleResize(dimensions)
    })
    .catch((e) =>{
        this.toast('error',e.message)
    })
}
```

I also fixed my other video issues as well by using the same method to load concurrent videos by removing the old source element and reinserting a newly created source element and using the additional video.load() and video.play() functions once the new source element is inserted.